# Synchronization in OpenMP

Tags: c++, multithreading, parallel-processing, synchronization, openmp

I am trying to implement a parallel algorithm with OpenMP. 
In principle I should have many threads writing and reading different components of a shared vector in an ashyncronous way.
There is a FOR loop in which the threads cycle and when a thread is in, let's say, row A of the loop it writes on a random component of the shared vector, while when it is in row B it reads a random component of the same shared vector.
It may happen that a thread would try to read a component of the shared vector while this component is written by another thread.
How to avoid inconsistency?

I read about locks and critical sections, but I think this is not the solution. For example, I can set a lock around row A in which the threads write in the shared vector, but does this prevent inconsistency if at the same time a thread in row B is trying to read that component?

Comment: The vector is not thread safe, so your data race scenario can happen. I think that the best solution (if possible) is to simply split the vector into sections and assign the sections to different threads. This way, you don't require any locks or atomics, as every thread has their own personal vector sub-section.

Comment: "let's say, row A of the loop it writes on a random component of the shared vector, while when it is in row B it reads a random component of the same shared vector": irrespective of the possible inconsistency, is your algorithm resilient to that? What I mean is, does the order in which the read and write actions to the "random component of the shared vector" happen have any severe consequence on the final result? If yes, maybe your algorithm isn't parallelisable (this way) after all. If not, there's probably a solution. Just post a working sequential version and we'll see.

Comment: Please show a [minimal but working example of what you want to do](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  At least show the scalar code.

Answer (score 2):

If the vector modifications are very simple single-value assignment operations and are not actually function calls, what you need are probably atomic reads and writes. With atomic operations, a read from an array element that is simultaneously being written to will either return the new value or the previous value; it will never return some kind of a bit mash of the old and the new value. OpenMP provides the `atomic` construct for that purpose. On certain architectures, including x86, atomics are far more lightweight than critical sections.

With more complex modifications you have to use critical sections. Those could be either named or anonymous. The latter are created using

```
#pragma omp critical
code block
```

Anonymous critical sections all map to the same synchronisation object, no matter what the position of the construct in the source code, therefore it is possible for unrelated code sections to get synchronised with all possible ill effects, like performance degradation or even unexpected deadlocks. That's why it is advisable to always use named critical sections. For example, the following two code segments will **not** get synchronised:

```
// -- thread i --                  // -- thread j --
...                                ...
#pragma omp critical(foo)  <       #pragma omp critical(foo)
do_something();            <       do_something;
...                                ...
#pragma omp critical(bar)          #pragma omp critical(bar)  <
do_something_else();               do_something_else();       <
...                                ...
```

(the code currently being executing by each thread is marked with `<`)

Note that critical sections bind to all threads of the program, without regard to the team to which the threads belong. It means that even code that executes in different parallel regions (a situation that mainly arises when nested parallelism is used) gets synchronised.